# Word keeps erroring out when controlled by Excel's VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a script that takes tables from Excel, copies then pastes the spreadsheets into Word which works fine most of the time, however, sometimes it errors with one the following errors:

> Run-time error '4605':
>
> This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is
> empty or not valid

or this error but it occurs less often

> Run-time error '4198':
>
> Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Selection' failed

The thing is that if I get any of these errors, I can just run the macro a few more times and it works as expected. What I believe is happening is that VBA forgets or loses the word document in memory.

What causes this and/or is there a fix to this issue?

Code example:

```
Sub TEST()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Set WordApp = New Word.Application
Dim n As Integer
n = 0

WordApp.Documents.Add
WordApp.Visible = True

Do Until n = 50
    n = n + 1
    Range("A1:C6").Select
    Range("C6").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    WordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    WordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine2, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Loop

WordApp.Quit 0
    
End Sub
```

You will need to have Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library active
(This macro is run on Excel VBA)

Comment: This kind of thing is difficult for us to trouble-shoot because we cannot reproduce/test - we don't have access to the workbook or the environment. Also, this is a "wall of code" - too much to take in by just reading it - with no comments as to its intentions. Just looking at it in an over-all way, I'd say the most likely problem comes from the use of `Selection`/`Select` for manipulating everything. Sometimes, what's supposed to be selected probably isn't, for some reason. For example, someone clicks somewhere during macro execution.

Comment: Therefore, my recommendation for trouble-shooting would be to first research on how to use the Office *objects*, directly, rather than selecting. The Excel folks have a Q&A about how to not use Select; I don't know of an equivalent for Word, but a lot of code in *answers* for Word use objects rather than Selection...